# Keep mouse within Ellipse2D

Tags: java, position, mouse-cursor

I know how to keep my mouse (my g.draw(mouseX, mouseY) cursor) within a Ellipse2D / Shape…

```
@Override
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    int x = e.getX(), y = e.getY();
    if(shape.contains(x, y)) {
        mouseMoveX = e.getX();
        mouseMoveY = e.getY();
    }
}
```

…but this locks the movement entirely when the mouse leaves said shape (until it returns).  IE it remains in the same position even though the actual cursor is moving around.  I would like the mouse to be able to move around the Ellipse even though the actual cursor is out.  Many of you may still be confused, sorry for that, if any more explanation is required I would be happy to oblige.  Also, first question here so please let me know if I broke any rules! Thanks.

PS: Sorry for any late responses, currently on dialup internet :(

Comment: Not sure of any "rules" that you've broken, but 1+ for posting code correctly in your first post. Having said that, I'd hate to use your application and find myself restricted.

Comment: The game is a sort of "shooter" and I only want the players cross-hair to be able to traverse within the Ellipse.  Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Perhaps then all you want to do is to set the cursor image to cross-hairs when it is located within the ellipse? Oh, and welcome to stackoverflow!

Comment: Hmmm interesting idea, however this still allows the cursor to become locked when leaving the ellipse.  One option would be to not draw the cross-hair when the cursor is out of the ellipse, but this then leaves the user without a cursor.  Another would be to simply draw the standard cursor, but this would leave the cross-hair again locked.  See my dilemma?

Comment: Where's the mouse listener attached to??

Comment: Mouse listener is attached to my Canvas, though mouse events are not an issue.  All listeners are behaving properly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do this would be to use the [`java.awt.Robot`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) class, which allows you to directly control the mouse and keyboard:

```
import java.awt.Robot;

...

Robot robot = new Robot(<your GraphicsDevice>);

...

@Override
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    int x = e.getX(), y = e.getY();
    if(shape.contains(x, y)) {
        mouseMoveX = e.getX();
        mouseMoveY = e.getY();
    }
    else {
        robot.mouseMove(mouseMoveX,mouseMoveY); // Assuming these are the previous coordinates.
    }
}
```

**Edit:** Okay, try this instead:

```
@Override
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    int x = e.getX(), y = e.getY();
    if (shape.contains(x, y)) {
        mouseMoveX = e.getX();
        mouseMoveY = e.getY();
    }
    else {
        // get angle of rotation
        double r = Math.atan2(y-shape.getCenterY(),x-shape.getCenterX());
        mouseMoveX = (int) (shape.getWidth()/2 * Math.cos(r) + shape.getCenterX());
        mouseMoveY = (int) (shape.getHeight()/2 * Math.sin(r) + shape.getCenterY());
    }
}
```

Comment: Not exactly what I was going for, but thanks for giving me the heads up about "Robot"!

Comment: @AtlasWegman What exactly were you looking for? This keeps the mouse inside the ellipse.

Comment: It indeed does, I had no problem with that.  My issue was keeping the cursor within the ellipse even when the mouse is not, allowing the cursor to mimic the mouse's actions, while remaining inside the ellipse.

Comment: @AtlasWegman So what is the cursor supposed to do? I'm confused on that point. It seems from your question that you didn't want the cursor to "lock" to one point on the ellipse- perhaps you wanted it to stick to the point on the ellipse between the mouse and the center?

Comment: I guess what I really want is to not actually lock the users cursor, but instead create a dot which mimics it while remaining in an ellipse. Does that make any more sense?  Thanks for the reply!

Comment: I still don't understand what is supposed to happen when the cursor gets to the edge- where should the dot go?

Comment: cursor (which is invisible) may leave the ellipse, but the dot representation must remain inside.

Comment: @AtlasWegman But _where_ inside? Doesn't the code you posted originally do that?

Comment: The code I posted does indeed do that, but it locks the cursor representation when it hits the all, I want to implement a sort of "sliding" to allow the cursor representation to move freely inside the ellipse, as well as freely along the walls of the ellipse.  My code allows for free movement within the ellipse, but not along the walls.

Answer (score 0):

An example of setting the cursor based on position:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;

import javax.swing.*;

public class CursorMagic extends JPanel {
   private static final int PREF_W = 600;
   private static final int PREF_H = 400;
   private static final Color ELLIPSE_COLOR = Color.red;
   private static final Color ELLIPSE_FILL_COLOR = Color.pink;
   private static final Stroke ELLIPSE_STROKE = new BasicStroke(3f);
   private Ellipse2D ellipse = new Ellipse2D.Double(PREF_W / 4, PREF_H / 4, PREF_W / 2, PREF_H / 2);

   public CursorMagic() {
      MyMouseAdapter mouseAdapter = new MyMouseAdapter();
      addMouseMotionListener(mouseAdapter);
   }

   @Override
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
      g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
      g2.setColor(ELLIPSE_FILL_COLOR);
      g2.fill(ellipse);
      g2.setColor(ELLIPSE_COLOR);
      g2.setStroke(ELLIPSE_STROKE);
      g2.draw(ellipse);
   }

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
   }

   private class MyMouseAdapter extends MouseAdapter {
      @Override
      public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent mEvt) {
         if (ellipse.contains(mEvt.getPoint())) {
            setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.CROSSHAIR_CURSOR));
         } else {
            setCursor(null);
         }
      }
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      CursorMagic mainPanel = new CursorMagic();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("CursorMagic");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: Interesting, though not exactly what I was going for.  For my purposes, I need the cross-hair to always remain visible and movable, regardless of mouse position, but still only stay within the ellipse.  Does that make any sense...at all :P  Thanks for the code though!